# GAE, JDO: how to cache a parent entity without it's children

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have a problem that whenever I load a parent entity (`User` in my case) and put it to **cache,** all it's children (in an **owned** relationship) are cached as well.

If I'm not wrong, the explanation is simple: the serialization process touches all properties of the object which causes that all child object are fetched as well. Eventually, the whole entity group is fetched.

How do I avoid that? The User entity group is planned to contain quite a lot of information and I don't want to cache it all at once. Not to mention that fetching all the child objects at once would be really demanding.

I came across `transient` modifier and was happy for a while until I realized, that not only it stops certain fields from getting cached, it also prevents those fields from getting persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to use the **detached version** of the entity. I load all entities using one function which looks right now something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E cachedEntity = (E) cache.get(cacheKey);

if (cachedEntity != null) {
    entity = cachedEntity;          
}
else {
    entity = pm.getObjectById(Eclass, key);
    cache.put(cacheKey, pm.detachCopy(entity));
}
```

The disadvantage is, that when I want to get the child objects, I have to explicitly attach the entity back using `entity = pm.makePersistent(entity)` which generates `Datastore.GET` RPC. However this doesn't happen very often and most likely I just want to access the entity itself, not its child objects, therefore it's quite efficient.

I came across an even better solution. The one RPC call when attaching the entity is there because the JDO checks whether the entity really exists in the datastore. And according to the **DataNucleus** documentation, this can be turned off just by setting `datanucleus.attachSameDatastore` to `false` in PMF. However it doesn't work for me, `Datastore.GET` is always called when attaching the object. If it worked, I could implicitly attach every object just after fetching it from the cache with zero cost and I wouldn't have to do it manually when needed.

Comment: Are you using the DataNucleus L2 cache as described here?  http://ukena.de/content/enabling-jdo-caching-google-app-engine  Or are you implementing your own caching logic using JCache or something similar?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my example, I am implementing my own caching logic using JCache. But it seems that internal DataNucleus L2 cache would be much better and simpler to use... I wish I had known about it before... On the other hand, I read the doc about DataNucleus L2 cache and I'm not sure about few things... what happens when I update an object? Or delete using a query? Will it be removed/updated? Is it guaranteed that I always get the latest up-to-date version of an object?